# Using blueimp-tmpl javascript plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, file-upload

I'm using the jQuery File Upload Plugin, more specifically I'm using the [java klaalo example](https://github.com/klaalo/jQuery-File-Upload-Java). The problem I'm facing is that I'd like to use the javascript template plugin, which is used and loaded by `jquery.fileupload-ui.js` file, in my `main.js` script file. In `jquery.fileupload-ui.js` file javascript template is loaded as it follows:

```
(function (factory) {
'use strict';
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // Register as an anonymous AMD module:
    define([
        'jquery',
        'tmpl',
        'load-image',
        './jquery.fileupload-fp'
    ], factory);
} else {
    // Browser globals:
    factory(
        window.jQuery,
        window.tmpl,
        window.loadImage
    );
}
```

I can't manage to use tmpl function in my main.js, should I load it once again? Can i doit without interfering with jquery-file-upload plugin?

Thanks in advance for any help
DeiviT